# Android Studio 1.4, experimental plugin, path to JNI folder?

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin

I'm using Android Studio 1.4 and the experimental plugin (com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0) with NDK support.

The project has one C file, and links the rest of the native code via a static library, like this:

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"
    ldFlags += ["-g"]
    ldFlags += ["-L/Users/me/Desktop/MyApp/app/src/main/jni", "-lnative"]
}
```

This works for me, linking libnative.a from the jni folder.

But I'd like to specify the location of the native library relative to the project.
How exactly do I do that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "native"
    ldFlags += ["-g"]
    ldLibs += ["-L", file("src/main/jni").absolutePath, "-lnative"]
}
```

Note that I use **ldLibs**, not **ldFlags** - these are used a bit differently to forge the linker command line.

Actually, if you want to add just one library, the preferred syntax would be

```
ldflags += file("src/main/jni/libnative.a").absolutePath
```

(there is no need for the linker to look for other libraries in this `"src/main/jni"` directory).

**file()** is relative to the current Module; use **File()** if you want to specify paths relative to current Project.

Comment: SO awesome, thank you!  Works like a charm.  Going with the second option.